# I can't implement run time permission on my device?

Tags: android

I want to implement internet run-time permission to my project, but I can't do it, I just added the below **code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello WOrld", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String permission = Manifest.permission.INTERNET;
                int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission);
                if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    String[] permission_list = new String[1];
                    permission_list[0] = permission;
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permission_list, 1);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // perform your action here

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

compileSdkVersion version: 28
Android gradle plugin version: 3.5.3
Gradle version: 5.4.1
Android studio version: 3.5.3
Android 8.1 (Oreo)

Comment: You don't need to ask for runtime permission for internet in android, you just need to add it to AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I also added in the manifest file

Comment: Then it should work fine, you don't need to ask for it manually

Comment: I wanted to get the information from the server but it didn't work, in the other project

Comment: There might be some other problem but this isn't a problem

Comment: Ok, but why my device doesn't show alert permission

Comment: For internet permission, it won't show dialog

Comment: call your method directly on button click. Your permission listeners will not be called for internet permission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the request for internet persmission required at runtime (Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435639/is-the-request-for-internet-persmission-required-at-runtime-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app lists *normal* permissions in its manifest (that is, permissions that don't pose much risk to the user's privacy or the device's operation), the system automatically grants those permissions to your app. The internet permission is normal permission. 
 If your app lists *dangerous* permissions in its manifest (that is, permissions that could potentially affect the user's privacy or the device's normal operation), such as the SEND_SMS permission above, the user must explicitly agree to grant those permissions.

For more information about normal and dangerous permissions, see Protection levels.

Comment: Protection levels - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous